# Why do my mammoth sunflower leaves look like this?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, sunflowers

These are what 2 of my mammoth sunflowers look like out of the 15 that I had originally planted.
[image]

[image]

I live in growing zone 4, in the Minnesota area, and the temperature has been a steady 80 degrees Fahrenheit for about 1 month now. I have been growing these sunflowers every year for 3 years and I have never seen such a (for a lack of better words) monstrosity before! I had already inspected the flowers for pests and common diseases, but there are no signs of powdery mildew or anything like that. I think I may have to do with using Ortho branded weed killer around them, but the strange part is that I had used weed killer around all sunflowers, but only 2 of them ended up like this? All of the other sunflowers that were exposed to this herbicide are growing like normally and don't have any problems.

I also want to point out the sunflowers are in a small land plot that get about 10+ hours of sunlight.

I water my sunflowers regularly, once every day, but if the temp is above 90 degrees I water them twice. I give them Miracle Grow All Purpose Plant Food to help them out, and yet, I don't see any changes in their shape or their new leaves.